# Typescript Mongoose Custom Document Creation Methods

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, mongoose, schema

When using typescript with mongoose, how to write a method for saving / creating a document.

Example: Contact entity contains phone number and name.

```
ContactSchema.methods.createContact = async function (name: string, phoneNr: string) {
  - custom controll flow
  - creation of ducement???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking up the difference between statics and methods in mongoose solved it. "When methods are used, 'this' is the object called method, and when using statistics, 'this' is the model itself, regardless of the object called statistics"." Source https://millo-l.github.io/Typescript-mongoose-methods-statics/